How to suspend schedular in QNX OS?
what is the equivalent API to FreeRTOS's 'vTaskSuspendAll()'?
I'm looking for a api in QNX to suspends the scheduler temporarily and resume back after some time.
API to Suspend all threads/tasks
API to resume all threads/tasks

You mean, like a system suicide call?

Such a call does not exist, and had better not exist. It would make the system unusable and non-recoverable.
Suspending the scheduler means that no other thread in the system can preempt the current one, including higher-priority threads and threads from other processes. That would be a violation of freedom from interference.
FreeRTOS and the like are not true operating systems, so they typically don't have such concerns. Any execution context is considered as privileged. That's not the case on QNX, where almost not execution context is privileged (the whole point of a micro-kernel OS).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
